# Disable dynamic sizing in UICollectionViewFlowLayout

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, autolayout, uikit, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a UICollectionViewFlowLayout assigned in UICollectionView. It's delegate method returns fixed CGSize in sizeForItemAtIndexPath. The problem is if UICollectionViewCell contains UIImageView or any other dynamically sized view with autolayout constraints that match leading, trailing, top, bottom to contentView, the cell resizes depending on the size of image in the imageView. Is it possible to get fixed size cells with UICollectionViewFlowLayout? I tried setting intrinsicContentSize for UIImageView in storyboard but it doesn't work.

Adding more details with code:

```
let numberOfItemsPerRow = 3
let spacingBetweenCells = CGFloat(40.0)
let sizeOfItem = CGFloat(210.0)

var sectionInsets:UIEdgeInsets {
    let margin:CGFloat = collectionView.bounds.width - CGFloat(numberOfItemsPerRow) * sizeOfItem - CGFloat(numberOfItemsPerRow - 1) * spacingBetweenCells
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 30, left: margin/2, bottom: 30, right: margin/2)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
   
    NSLog("Cell size \(sizeOfItem)")
    return CGSize(width: sizeOfItem, height: sizeOfItem)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return sectionInsets
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return spacingBetweenCells
}
```

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

```
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "mediaCell", for: indexPath) as! ThumbViewCell
    
    cell.mediaItem = mediaItems[indexPath.item]
    
    if let thumbURL = mediaItem.thumbURL, let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: thumbURL.path) {
        cell.thumbnailView.image = image
        cell.thumbnailView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    } 
     
    return cell
}
```

[image]

[image]

And here is the output. It clearly scales with the image size.

[image]

Here is console log:

```
 2022-06-04 11:47:34.599808+0400 SmrtImageCam[17794:1098605] The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x155d0d9c0>, and it is attached to <UICollectionView: 0x156023400; frame = (262.5 0; 931.5 834); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x280438690>; layer = <CALayer: 0x280a7f560>; contentOffset: {0, -50}; contentSize: {931.5, 770}; adjustedContentInset: {50, 0, 20, 0}; layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x155d0d9c0>; dataSource: <SmrtImageCam.LibraryController: 0x1574082e0>>.


 Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.
The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because: the item width must be less than the width of the UICollectionView minus the section insets left and right values, minus the content insets left and right values.
 Please check the values returned by the delegate.
 The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x155d0d9c0>, and it is attached to <UICollectionView: 0x156023400; frame = (262.5 0; 931.5 834); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x280438690>; layer = <CALayer: 0x280a7f560>; contentOffset: {0, -50}; contentSize: {931.5, 770}; adjustedContentInset: {50, 0, 20, 0}; layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x155d0d9c0>; dataSource: <SmrtImageCam.LibraryController: 0x1574082e0>>.
Make a symbolic breakpoint at  UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.
```

Comment: That's confusing... if you are explicitly returning a size, the cells should not "dynamically" change size. Are you *sure* `sizeForItemAt` is being called? You also have the option of setting `.itemSize` on your flow layout.

Comment: @DonMag Yes, it's called. I will update the question with more details.

Comment: @DonMag Question has been updated with more details.

Comment: @DonMag It sounds weird, but setting estimatedSize to .none in flow layout solved the problem as described in [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/126193) answer on Apple developer forums.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's a known bug in iOS, but setting estimatedSize to .none for UICollectionViewFlowLayout in the Storyboard solves the problem as described in [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/126193) answer in Apple Developer Forums.